# How to get object property in lwc?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have 3 class:

```
public class FromJSON {

    public cls_coord coord;
    public cls_weather[] weather;
    public String base; //stations
    public cls_main main;
    public Integer visibility;  //10000
    public cls_wind wind;
    public cls_clouds clouds;
    public Integer dt;  //1485789600
    public cls_sys sys;
    public Integer id;  //2643743
    public String name; //London
    public Integer cod; //200

    class cls_coord {
        public Double lon;  //-0.13
        public Double lat;  //51.51
    }
    class cls_weather {
        public Integer id;  //300
        public String main; //Drizzle
        public String description;  //light intensity drizzle
        public String icon; //09d
    }
    class cls_main {
        public Double temp; //280.32
        public Integer pressure;    //1012
        public Integer humidity;    //81
        public Double temp_min; //279.15
        public Double temp_max; //281.15
    }
    class cls_wind {
        public Double speed;    //4.1
        public Integer deg; //80
    }
    class cls_clouds {
        public Integer all; //90
    }
    class cls_sys {
        public Integer type;    //1
        public Integer id;  //5091
        public Double message;  //0.0103
        public String country;  //GB
        public Integer sunrise; //1485762037
        public Integer sunset;  //1485794875
    }
}

public with sharing class UpdateWeather {

    public FromJSON updateWeather() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndpoint('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        FromJSON weather = new FromJSON();
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            weather = (FromJSON) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), FromJSON.class);
             System.debug('weather = ' + weather);
        }       
        return weather;
    }
}

public with sharing class WeatherViewController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static FromJSON getWeather() {
        UpdateWeather updateWeather = new UpdateWeather();
        FromJSON weather = new FromJSON();
        weather = updateWeather.updateWeather();

        return weather;

    }
}
```

lwc:
js:

```
renderedWeather() {

        getWeather()
            .then(result => {
                this.weather = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.weather = undefined;
            });
    }

<template if:true={weather}>
                {weather.base}
         </template>
```

in lwc i get error [object Object]:

                {weather.base} //--> [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply pass to the page and use JSON.parse () on the page.

```
@track weather; //use parse to JSON  
@wire(getWeather, { searchKey: '$searchKey' })
    wiredWeather({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.weather = JSON.parse(data);
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = JSON.parse(error.body.message);
            this.weather = undefined;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You clearly mean, pass it as a JSON string and parse it on the client. Sure, it's an option. I guess it depends on whether you need to add any value on the server side. I clearly didn't suggest this before due to the way you framed the question, showing the use of a server-side data object.

Comment: (I suggest you improve your answer a bit to clarify what you mean and to discuss the relative benefits of the two approaches)

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you have imported the WeatherViewController.getWeather method as the getWeather imperatively called Apex then the issue is that you have not annotated the various attributes in your cls_* data object classes. Each attribute you want to return must be annotated with @AuraEnabled, like:

```
public class FromJSON {
    @AuraEnabled
    public cls_coord coord;

    @AuraEnabled
    public cls_weather[] weather;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String base; //stations

    ...
```

You have to do this at each level of your "JSON", so remember to annotate the attributes in cls_weather as well, for example.

Oddly, the classes themselves do not need to be annotated.

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm) for details.

Comment: only works for weather.base   but does not work weather.main.temp_min

Comment: Did you annotate every attribute in that path? I.e. you need both "main" and "temp_min" annotated.

Comment: oh.. its worked, is this a best practice?

Comment: This is what you have to do.

Comment: @PhilW you have to add  `{ get; set; }`

Comment: I admit the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm) says to use properties, and doesn't mention use of public attributes. However, it works with public attributes too. Indeed, it would be quite ridiculous to require the values to always be properties instead of also supporting public attributes.